# ASP.NET Custom Web Control in App_Code VS In Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, custom-controls, .net-assembly

I've implemented a few asp.net server controls, I've put them into **App_Code** Folder.
Will it **slow down** website working as this folder is compiled at runtime?

And 2nd. How to move them into seperate dll file? (reference some good links).

Comment: I think more classes in App_Code will slow down the compile time only, but once it's compiled the time should be normal.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a dll.  Simply create a "library" project in VS and put the controlls in there.  Add this library (.dll) to any project you want and you'll have your controls.  I'm not providing links because you can probably do this without looking at any documentation (it's simple, just create the project as a library, build it to .dll, then link to any project).

As yogi said, you may not gain performance, but it's a control and should be in a "library" for ease of reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Hello levanlevi you can try with this article, they are very interessant

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/4yf3whkx(v=vs.90).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7708/Web-Custom-Controls

You must just create your control in library and add reference to this library.
Finally you must register this assembly before use